# how to convert foreach to linq to get the element

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

How can I convert below foreach to linq?
I need to get the element.

```
foreach (var x in LoadData)
                item.Comments = x.Inventory.Comments;
```

Comment: You are overwriting it every iteration, aren't you?

Comment: for this code it would be `if (LoadData.Count() > 0) { item.Comments = LoadData.Last().Inventory.Comments; }` which is not in any way better (assuming your original code is correct, which is unlikely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you want to use [`Select` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb298787%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
LoadData.Select(x => x.Inventory.Comments);
```

**Edit:**
And if you want to get last element, you can use `Last` function:

```
LoadData.Select(x => x.Inventory.Comments).Last();
```

Or

```
LoadData.Last().Inventory.Comments;
```

Comment: i got cannot convert type system.collections.generic.ienumerable<string> to string

Comment: @momokjaaaaa, If you want to get last element from collection you can use `Last` function (I expand my answer).

Comment: i use FirstOrDefault.